# Unable to install aws-sam-cli using pip on Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I'm at my wits end.

I'm trying to install aws-sam-cli so that I can test AWS Lambda functions locally. I've followed all the tutorials I can find but I'm stuck.

I've installed docker and python 3.7 onto my local machine but when I try to install aws-sam-cli using:

```
pip install aws-sam-cli
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli) (from versions: 219, 223)

No matching distribution found for pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
```

After much searching and messing I've drawn a blank. Can anyone help?

I'm using Windows Powershell as my environment but I'm new that. I'm also new to Docker and Python. There's probably something obvious I've missed but I'm failing to find it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I solved this. I had installed Python 3.7 and it would appear that something wasn't compiled against it (not sure what).

I had to role that back and install Python 3.6.6 and all worked fine.

Hope this helps someone else.