# AWS SAM not installing with Python 3.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

From [AWS's Install SAM CLI documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/sam-cli-requirements.html), I should run

```
pip install aws-sam-cli
```

However, I get the error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli) (from versions: 219, 223)
No matching distribution found for pypiwin32==220; sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6" (from docker>=3.3.0->aws-sam-cli)
```

System information:

- Windows10
- Python 3.7
- PIP 10.0.1

One solution recommended by Spike ([Unable to install aws-sam-cli using pip on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082241/unable-to-install-aws-sam-cli-using-pip-on-windows-10)) is to revert to Python 3.6.6. Does anyone know when/how Amazon will fix this issue? Will I need to re-install something else, or will just periodically running `pip install aws-sam-cli` be good enough to know when the problem is resolved.

Comment: It's docker-py's problem; see: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1926.

Comment: You could try modifying the requirements.txt file and just see what happens; could break stuff, or it could work. It sounds like from that forum that the maintainers of docker-py just haven't had time to verify if the newer version of one of their dependencies is compatible.